# ”No module named ogr” when installing QGIS plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ogr, qgis-2.6, qgis-cloud

In QGIS 2.6.1, when I try to install the FlowMapper and QGIS Cloud plugins, I get an error - "The plugin is broken. Python said: no module named ogr" - giving me the only option of removing them. Other plugins work fine.

Because of this, when I open 2.6.1, this message comes up:

```
Nu s-a putut încărca pluginul FlowMapper datorită unei erori în timpul apelării metodei classFactory()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 208, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Cezar/.qgis2/python/plugins\FlowMapper\__init__.py", line 24, in classFactory
    from flowmapper import FlowMapper
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Cezar/.qgis2/python/plugins\FlowMapper\flowmapper.py", line 24, in 
    import ogr
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named ogr


Versiune Python:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


Versiune QGIS:
2.6.1-Brighton Brighton, e2a51df

Cale Python: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/Cezar/.qgis2
/python', u'C:/Users/Cezar/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis
/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1
\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps
\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps
\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1
\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1
\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-
2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-
2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages
\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1
\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 
'C:\\Users\\Cezar\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\DigitizingTools\\tools']
```

Before this version, I used QGIS 2.4, which I forgot to delete, so I still have it. I tested the plugins there and they work very well.
Are the plugins incompatible with version 2.6.1, or is there another problem?

Comment: I tested these plugins in QGIS 2.6.0 and they loaded up fine. Hopefully someone with 2.6.1 can test this since I'm sticking with my version for now :). Alternatively, you can try downloading the plugins manually from the [repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) and extract the plugin folder to `C:\Users\(your user name)\.qgis2\python\plugins\`. Restart QGIS and try and enable it from _Manage and Install Plugins_ menu.

Comment: The same happens after a manual install and after a clean reinstall of QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved! It's a module PATH Python console problem.

In QGIS Brighton/apps/Python27/Lib/site-packages create osgeo.pth (Administrators) file and put

# .pth file for the osgeo extensions osgeo

start QGIS and install flowmapper ;)

Clarifying, after create osgeo.pth file, open him and just add in first line the word osgeo, save and run QGIS! Done.

Answer (score 1):

The QGIS Cloud plugin is broken for me too on Windows XP and 7 with 32-bit QGIS 2.6.1 standalone.

You can grab an older version from here:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgiscloud/version/0.11.11/

and extract it to `C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins` or the equivalent on other OS.

The version 0.11.11 starts for me without complaining. But don't try to update the plugin!

Feel free to add your case to https://github.com/qgiscloud/qgis-cloud-plugin/issues/16 to get the latest version fixed.

Unfortunately, thre is no older version of FlowMapper that runs without problem.

---

**Update**

Both plugins install on Ubuntu 14.04 without complaints.

Comment: I added the version you suggested but it just comes up on the plugin manager as 'This plugin is broken Missing metadata file'. Any idea where this metadata file is? More importantly has anyone got any idea why this is happening to a few people, it's surely the same software we've all got?

Comment: If you have extracted the plugin correctly, you should have `C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgiscloud\metadata.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, that's all sorted now, it was just an error in the way my archive software unpacked the folder. Plugin installed successfully, but I cannot upload any files. I'm guessing maybe a firewall issue, but there's no information on what connection to allow so I've emailed the developers.